# How can I create a page in Drupal that doesn't appear in the Drupal configuration menu?

Tags: hooks

How can I create a page in Drupal that doesn't appear in the Drupal configuration menu? For example: admin/config/handler, but the only way is the direct link. There is no link in the configuration menu. Which hook function should I use?

```
$items['admin/config/handler'] = array(
    'title' => 'Handler',
    'description' => 'Just some info here.',
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('handler_form'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and define a path with the type element set to MENU_CALLBACK. The API docs linked above has an example for the path **example/feed**.

Comment: You mean this way: `'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,`, right? It doesn't work on this way, he is still available on the menu.

Comment: Yes. Have you tried flushing your cache? Paths defined with `'type' => MENU_CALLBACK` should register a path only without a menu item.

Comment: Yes I also tried to flush the cache. But no success here.. I edit my post with the code.

Comment: Try investigating the `menu_router` table; you should see your **admin/config/handler** path registered there with the `type` column set to 0. Also take a look at the `menu_links` table, there should be NO corresponding entry for **admin/config/handler** under `link_path`. If there is, you may created a custom menu link or some other module is registering that path.

Comment: There is a link under `link_path`. What do you mean with custom menu link? Thank you!

Comment: You can define any custom menu links (not defined by modules) under **Structure > Menus > Management**. You can tell it's a custom menu link since it will have a `delete` link in the `operations` column.

Comment: I disbabled the menu link under **Structure > Menus > Management** and it's working now. Can I do this also programmatically? Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! If this answers your question, mark it as answered, and ask a new question about programmatically disabling menus; Drupal Answers isn't a message forum so long discussion threads are discouraged here. It will also boost your rep so access the chat features here.